# UK citizen applying for Working Holiday Visa to New Zealand, is the date of intent to travel flexible?

Tags: visas, new-zealand, working-holiday

I'm applying for a visa before booking flights. The visa application requires a date of intent to travel. I'll be going mid-October but don't have a specific date yet as I haven't booked flights. If I was to put the 10th October, would it be a problem if I ended up travelling slightly after this date?

Answer (score 3):

There is no obligation for you to arrive on your date of intent to travel. From [United Kingdom Working Holiday Visa](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/united-kingdom-working-holiday-visa) (click on "All visa conditions"):

> You must come to New Zealand within 12 months of the date your visa is granted.
>
> After you arrive in New Zealand, you can come and go from New Zealand as many times as you like before your visa expires.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely flexible.

What matters is that once you are granted your visa you get 1 year to enter the country (unless different from Australia).